# tree nodes defined with a tree

Tags: python, tree

I am working with trees in python and this is the problem I am trying to solve.

All my nodes have lists. For every parent, the children's lists are extracted from the parents list by removing one element at a time.

Let's say **node1** is the list1 **[1,2,3]** I want to have 3 children (in this case) for node1 where every child is a list extracted from list 1 by removing one item at a time. and so **node2=[2,3]**  **node3=[1,3]**  and **node4=[1,2]**

I am working with **anytree** library but I can't find enough documentation on complex nodes.
I currently have written this method but I am doubting the syntax:

```
  from anytree import Node, RenderTree
 #some othercode
    def createNodes(parentnode):
        for i in (0,K,1):
            childnode=Node(parentnode.pop(i), parent=parentnode)
            return childnode
```

does this code works as a solution? 
p.s: this is the tutorial I followed on Anytrees 
[https://anytree.readthedocs.io/en/2.6.0/intro.html#basics][1]

Comment: It's not clear to me what part of your problem you're actually asking about. Do you need to know how to get the lists you name from the starting list, or do you have a question about your tree library and its syntax? Those are not very closely related topics!

Comment: @Blckknght Thank you for the feedback, I have modified the question, I hope it is clear now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.child = 3*[None]
        for i in range(len(data)):
            elem = data.pop(i)
            self.child[i] = data
            print(self.child[i])
            data.insert(i, elem)


data = [1, 2, 3]
root = Node(data)
```

output:

```
[2, 3]
[1, 3]
[1, 2]
```

Alternatively, you can try this:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.data = data

def createNodes(parentnode):
    data = parentnode.data
    for i in range(len(data)):
        elem = data.pop(i)
        childnode = Node(data, parent=parentnode)
        print(childnode.data)
        data.insert(i, elem)

root = Node([1, 2, 3], None)
createNodes(root)
```

output:

```
[2, 3]
[1, 3]
[1, 2]
```

Comment: thank you for your feedback your code does work for the example. However, what I need is to use recursively(or in a loop) a certain method and create children when some certain conditions are satisfied

Comment: @basel117, check my alternative solution. This may be what you are looking for.